# Why does my custom UITableViewCell never change from the prototype?

Tags: ios, ios6

I have a custom class that extends UITableViewCell.  It has two labels and a UISegmentedControl.

Here is the cellForRowAtIndexPath() that I configured.  When I inspect "cell" in the debugger it has all the data I'm providing.  But somehow that data never gets applied.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";
    CustomGameCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[CustomGameCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    MyData *my_data = [rows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UILabel *my_date = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    my_date.text = my_data.myDate;
    [cell setMyDateLabel:my_date];

    UILabel *my_question = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    my_question.text = my.question;
    [cell setMyQuestionLabel:my_question];


    UISegmentedControl *my_choices = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]
                                        initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:my.firstChoice, my.secondChoice, nil]];
    [my_choices setSelectedSegmentIndex:my.choice];
    [cell setMyChoiceSegments:my_choices];

    return cell
}
```

The data that I want displayed is currently in an array I create in viewDidLoad() which is accessible to cellForRowAtIndexPath() through the "rows" var.

When I run the code in the simulator I get three rows in the table representing the three elements in the array I created in viewDidLoad().  However, the content of those rows look exactly like what I defined in the storyboard.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Where are you defining the layout of your cell? In a NIB? In your storyboard? Programmatically in your `initWithStyle` of `CustomGameCell`? The implementation details vary a little based upon which approach you use, but you definitely need to either define NIB or prototype cell in your storyboard, or programmatically create the controls, set their frames, perform `addSubview` so they're included in the cell, etc.
2. Your code is adding new `UILabel` objects, not adding them as a subview to anything, doing it regardless if you're using a dequeued cell or not, etc. So there are numerous problems here. To see examples of how you might properly use a custom cell, see [Customizing Cells](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW18) in the *Table View Programming Guide.* But, like I said, the details vary a bit based upon how you're designing your subclassed `UITableViewCell` layout, so I hesitate to propose any code until you specify how you're designing your user interface.

Answer (score 2):

You must have added the labels and segmentcontrol in the cells content view of the cell, if not then please do so.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";
    CustomGameCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[CustomGameCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    MyData *my_data = [rows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.myDateLabel.text = my_data.myDate;

    cell.myQuestionLabel.text = my.question;

    [cell.myChoiceSegments setSelectedSegmentIndex:my.choice];

    [cell autorelease];
    return cell
}
```

Also use `autorelease` for the memory management.

Comment: I'll give that a try. But do I need to use autorelease with ARC?

Comment: @DarrellBrogdon You don't. Shekhar obviously assumed you weren't using ARC. (I don't know why anyone wouldn't just use ARC nowadays!)